# Problem in Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android

I am new in Android.

I have developed a small application with two `Activity`.
Some audio sounds are loaded with the starting of the first `Activity`.

When a button (Next_Button) is pressed another activity is come to front.
I have another button (Previous_Button) in the second `Activity` which will make the first `Activity` come in front when i pressed it.
But when i call the first `Activity` from the second `Activity` it again load the sound clips which is time wasting.
So i want to back the first `Activity` from second `Activity` without reloading the sounds i.e. sounds are load once and exist till the application exist though i move to another activity.

Please help me.

Best Wishes

Md. Fazla Rabbi

Answer (score 0):

Put the loading of the sound clip in the onCreate() of your first activity. This should be called once when the Activity is created. Put the playing of the clip in onResume() which is called every time the Activity is made visible. Stop the playing in the onPause() if that is appropriate.

Comment: Actually my problem is:  in the Back_Button in my Second activity i have used code as: public void onClick(View v) {                         Intent ints=new  Intent(Second_Activity.this,First_Activity.class);
startActivity(ints); }                                                  So when i pressed the button it again reload the sound in my First_Activity. I have used onResume() on my First_Activity but the result is same. Is there any change in the Intent object to back to First_Activity without reloading the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' add the button to come back in the second `Activity`.
There already exists a button for that in Android devices - it's called the Back Button :)
That way when you press back in the second Activity the first one shouldn't restart.

Read more about Activity lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle